# HashMap doesn't copy object

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

in Java I have a ResultSet object which I use to fill an HashMap Object, in this way:

```
        rs = db.executeQuery(query);
        rs.last();
        rows = rs.getRow();
        rs.beforeFirst();
        String current;
        String[] current_columns = new String[rows];
        int x;
        for(int i=0; i<n_col; i++){ //scroll columns
            x=0;
            while(rs.next()){ // scroll rows
                current = rs.getString(columns[i]);
                current_columns[x++] = current;
            }

            //a little output debug
            System.out.print("hm.put("+columns[i]+", {");
            for(int j=0; j<current_columns.length; j++)
                System.out.print(current_columns[j]+" ");
            System.out.println("});");
            //end of output debug

            hm.put(columns[i], current_columns);

            rs.beforeFirst();

        }
```

The output debug prints:

> hm.put(a, {a1 a2} );
>
> hm.put(b, {b1 b2} );

So, if I write the instruction hm.get("a") it should return me the array string {"a1", "a2"}, while if I write hm.get("b") it should return me the array string {"b1", "b2"}.

But, in practice, when I try to get the values, the hashmap returns me always the last array that I put, regardless of the key.
So if I write the instructions:

```
System.out.println(hm.get("a")[0]);
System.out.println(hm.get("b")[0]);
```

it prints:

> b1
>
> b1

Why does the hashmap have this behavior ? Where is the problem ?

Comment: What if you print the _actual `HashMap`_, rather than your debug output? I think you have a bug elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are always using the same array so all the keys are mapped to the same object, you should declare it **inside** the loop and not outside.

```
    int x;
    for(int i=0; i<n_col; i++){ 
        // This time you declare a NEW array each time
        String[] current_columns = new String[rows];
        x=0;
        while(rs.next()){ 
            current = rs.getString(columns[i]);
            current_columns[x++] = current;
        }

        System.out.print("hm.put("+columns[i]+", {");
        for(int j=0; j<current_columns.length; j++)
            System.out.print(current_columns[j]+" ");
        System.out.println("});");

        hm.put(columns[i], current_columns);

        rs.beforeFirst();
    }
```

Comment: That's precisely the problem : he is writing several times into a single array, thus overriding the previously written values

Comment: Yes it works, thank you very much.
I thought that when I put an object into a hashmap it would be copied, instead pretty much the pointer is passed.